# How to use the same code to create multiple dags in airflow

Tags: airflow

I am thinking of a way if possible to run multiple (differently labeled DAGs) in airflow (that use different configs  like route, but the logic is same)

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**

You can create a DAG template with subtasks creating a DAG Factory.

Utilise globals() and save the Python code into the dags_folder, Airflow will load it.

```py
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from datetime import datetime


def dag_factory(
    dag_id: str, schedule_interval: str = "@daily", default_args: dict = None
):
    def print_statement(*args):
        print("Hello World")
        print(f"This is DAG number {dag_id}")

    dag = DAG(dag_id, schedule_interval=schedule_interval, default_args=default_args)

    with dag:
        task = PythonOperator(
            task_id="print_statement",
            python_callable=print_statement,
        )

    return dag


for number in range(1, 10):
    dag_id = f"test_dag_{number}"

    default_args = {
        "start_date": datetime(2021, 1, 1),
    }

    globals()[dag_id] = dag_factory(dag_id, default_args=default_args)
```

**Solution 2**

Here is the modern approach to dynamic dags, which takes advantage of the newer dag and task decorators.

```py
from airflow.decorators import dag, task
from datetime import datetime

configs = {
    'dag_1': 'This is dag 1',
    'dag_2': 'This is dag 2',
}

for dag_name, dag_config in configs.items():

    @dag(
        dag_id=dag_name,
        schedule_interval='@daily',
        start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1)
    )

    def dynamic_dag():
        @task
        def print_data(msg):
            print(msg)
        
        print_data(dag_config)

    dynamic_dag()
```

You find out more from the [Official Docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/dynamic-dag-generation.html#).